# Wordpress check url consists specific php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to check in Wordpress admin page URL consists a specific php file. Suppose, I have an URL

```
http://localhost/candidate/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=candidate-form
```

Now i would like to check if the `edit.php` exists in this URL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strpos`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/candidate/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=candidate-form';
$search = 'edit.php';

if (strpos($url, $search) !== false) {
   echo 'found edit.php in url';
}
```